# GAE PHP App only displays index / homepage

Tags: php, google-app-engine, app.yaml

On the homepage index.htm page there is a link to a signUp.htm page, the link isn't working.

I believe it's a YAML issue:

```
handlers:
- url: /images
  static_dir: images

- url: /.*
  script: index.htm
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a static handler for html files. Put it before your catch all handler .*

```
- url: /(.*\.(htm$|html$))
  static_files: \1
  upload: (.*\.(htm$|html$))
```

Comment: Thanks seems to work. Couldn't find that in the documentation, not sure how I could have worked it out. Thanks again awesome!

Comment: Don't know how this could be more clear -> https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/config/appconfig

Comment: I was searching for htm or html files and the documentation talks about images. I now realise they are both static and so treated similarly.